# How can I test an Angular service method that manipulates a local variable and returns an observable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-services

Assuming a service like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class PageNavService {
    private _expanded = true;
    private pageNavExpanded = new Subject<any>();

    public togglePageNav(): void {
        this._expanded = !this._expanded
        this.pageNavExpanded.next(this._expanded);
    }

    public setPageNavState(expanded) {
        this._expanded = expanded;
        this.pageNavExpanded.next(this._expanded);
    }

    public getPageNavState(): Observable<any> {
        return this.pageNavExpanded.asObservable();
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

How can I test the `togglePageNav()` method?

This is my attempt:

```
describe('PageNavService', () => {
    let service;
    let state;

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [PageNavService]
    }));

    beforeEach(inject([PageNavService], svc => {
        service = svc;
        service.getPageNavState().subscribe((s) => {
            state = s;
        });
    }));

    describe('togglePageNav method', () => {
        it('should reverse the navbar state', () => {
            service.togglePageNav();
            expect(state).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

However, the test fails with this:

> Expected false to be truthy.

Comment: `getPageNavState` is a method, you have to call it (`service.getPageNavState()` instead of `service.getPageNavState`)

Comment: Thank you, That resolved the syntax error, but the test still fails as though the observable isn't returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you initial state is `true`, the test can't succeed, let me explain.

```
describe('PageNavService', () => {
    let service;
    let state;

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [PageNavService]
    }));

    beforeEach(inject([PageNavService], svc => {
        service = svc;
        //At this moment, the state inside the service is true
        service.getPageNavState().subscribe((s) => {
            state = s;
        });
    }));

    describe('togglePageNav method', () => {
        it('should reverse the navbar state', () => {
            //Toggle will change the state from its initial state to an opposite one, making it false
            service.togglePageNav();
            //The test fails because the state is now false.
            expect(state).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

You can either change the initial state (`private _expanded`) to `false` or change your test to expect `false`, because that's what you are supposed to get at the moment.

Comment: You're right. Once I resolved the syntax error pointed out by others, and once I removed the leading `expect()` statement, which apparently preceded the subscription, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method **`getPageNavState()`**,

```
 service.getPageNavState().subscribe((s) => {
            state = s;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntax fix, but the test still fails. It's as though it doesn't get the observable.